# SQLite database not created in Phonegap app (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

When I test my app in Safari (desktop) or in a virtual device I can see the database is created as expected but if I run the same app on a physical device (galaxy note tab) I can see the /data folder is empty in DDMS file explorer and I cannot find a database.

I am attempting to create the database in the onDeviceReady function which I can see is firing as expected.

Should I need root access to this device?  I checked and it is not rooted?

Here is my config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id = "uk.co.epwin.ecobuild2013"
    version = "0.0.1"
    versionCode = "1">

<name>Ecobuild 2013</name>

<description>
app for the 2013 Ecobuild exhibition
</description>

<author href="http://www.epwin.co.uk" email="info@epwin.co.uk">
    Mike Mardon | Epwin Group Design Studio
</author>

<!-- ICONS -->
<icon src="images/icons/icon.png" /> <!-- default 72 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" /> <!-- iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS, iPod Touch 2G, 3G -->
<icon src="images/icons/ios/icon72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" /> <!-- iPad, iPad 2, iPad mini -->
<icon src="images/icons/ios/icon114.png" width="114" height="114" /> <!-- iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod Touch 4G -->
<icon src="images/icons/ios/icon144.png" width="144" height="144" /> <!-- iPad 3, iPad 4 -->
<icon src="images/icons/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" /> <!-- 36 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" /> <!-- 48 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" /> <!-- 72 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" /> <!-- 96 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/bb/icon.png" gap:platform="blackberry" /> <!-- 72 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/bb/icon_hover.png" gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover"/> <!-- 72 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/winphone/icon.png" gap:platform="winphone" /> <!-- 57 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/winphone/tileicon.png" gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" /> <!-- 72 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/webos/icon.png" gap:platform="webos" /> <!-- 29 pixels -->
<icon src="images/icons/webos/miniicon.png" gap:platform="webos" gap:role="mini" /> <!-- 15 pixels -->

<!-- SPLASH SCREENS -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/splash.png" /> <!-- default 320x480 pixels -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/ios/1024x768.png" width="1024" height="768" /> <!-- iPad 1, iPad 2, iPad mini -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/ios/768x1024.png" width="768" height="1024" /> <!-- iPad 1, iPad 2, iPad mini -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/ios/320x480.png" width="320" height="480" /> <!-- iPh 3G / 3GS, iPod Touch 2, iPod Touch 3 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/ios/640x960.png" width="640" height="960" /> <!-- iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod Touch 4 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/ios/640x1136.png" width="640" height="1136" /> <!-- iPhone 5, iPod Touch 5 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" /> <!-- 200x320 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" /> <!-- 320x480 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" /> <!-- 480x800 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" /> <!-- 720x1280 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/bb/splash.png" gap:platform="blackberry" /> <!-- BlackBerry 250x250 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/winphone/splash.jpg" gap:platform="winphone" /> <!-- Windows Phone 7 480x800 -->
<gap:splash src="images/splash/webos/splash.png" gap:platform="webos" /> <!-- WebOS 64x64 -->

<!-- GENERAL PREFERENCES -->
<!--<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.2.0" /> if unspecified it will build with latest version--> 
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" /> 
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" /> <!-- handset, tablet only applies to ios, other are universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" /> 

<!-- iOS PREFERENCES -->
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" /> <!-- if screen "bounces" when scrolled beyond top or bottom on iOS -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />  <!-- if true, iOS won't apply its gloss to app's home screen icon -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" /> <!-- if true, all links (even with target blank) will open in webview -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" /> <!-- if set to false, app will continue to run on suspend -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" /> <!-- show spinner on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" /> <!-- if false, it must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->

<!-- ANDROID PREFERENCES -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" /> <!-- min Android 2.1 -->
<!-- <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="17" /> max Android 4.2 -->
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" /> <!-- internalOnly, auto or preferExternal -->
<preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="5000" /> <!-- 5 seconds  - for auto-hide behaviour call    navigator.splashscreen.hide(); in the device-ready method-->        
<preference name="load-url-timeout" value="20000" /> <!-- 20 seconds -->
<plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" />

<!-- BLACKBERRY PREFERENCES -->
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />

<!-- PHONEGAP API FEATURES PREFERENCES -->
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

<!-- If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/> -->

<!-- to enable individual permissions use the following examples -->
<!--<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>-->
<!--<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>-->
<!--<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>-->
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<!--<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>-->
<!--<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>-->
<!--<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>-->
<!--<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>-->
```

Comment: sorry just to reiterate, it does work on my AVD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a rooted device to expand the `data` folder on the file explorer. It looks empty but it's not.

If it works on your avd it should work on your device as well, you just can't access the database files on the file explorer.

Comment: thanks for this, I thought as much and subsequent tests confirm your reply!